# How to group a DataFrame and divide rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I need to group a dataframe by "Day" and divide the values from column "Count" ("Clicked"/"Delivered")

| Day | Status | Channel | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-08 | Delivered | SMS | 288322 |
| 2022-11-08 | Clicked | SMS | 1132 |
| 2022-11-13 | Delivered | SMS | 246203 |
| 2022-11-13 | Clicked | SMS | 4684 |
| 2022-11-19 | Delivered | SMS | 154872 |
| 2022-11-19 | Clicked | SMS | 1222 |
| 2022-11-20 | Delivered | SMS | 253716 |
| 2022-11-20 | Clicked | SMS | 2384 |

I used pandas .groupby() to group by "Day", but i don´t know how to specify to divide "Count". Like if I needed to sum values I'd use .sum(), but there isn´t a .divide() unfortunally.

Comment: [Show us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) the code you have written so far.

Comment: you dont need groupby for this, if each date of yours has only 1 clicked and 1 delivered row. this can be solved with `.unstack()`. do check my answer for details.

Comment: As far as I understood this question, the table is what TS wants to get.

Comment: No, the table shown is what OP is using as input. the output expected is a day level dataframe with a column that is the division of the "clicked" count for that date, by the "delivered" count for the same date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### 1. Using `.unstack()` (when one row of each type exists)

You don't need `groupby` for this if you only have 1 clicked and 1 delivered value per date (as your example suggests).

You can use `.unstack()` to get the result you need. It doesn't need any sorting of rows as well, only that there are 2 rows per date (one for Clicked, and other for Delivered). Here is how the 2-3 line code below works -

1. Set Day and Status as multiindex
2. Unstack the Status index to get 2 columns, `Clicked` and `Delivered`
3. Simply divide these 2 columns after that and reset index

```
s = df.set_index(['Day','Status'])['Count'].unstack() #<-- Unstack status index
s['Ratio'] = s['Clicked']/s['Delivered']              #<-- Divide clicked & delivered
s = s.reset_index()                                   #<-- Reset index
print(s)
```

```
Status         Day  Clicked  Delivered     Ratio
0       2022-11-08     1132     288322  0.003926
1       2022-11-13     4684     246203  0.019025
2       2022-11-19     1222     154872  0.007890
3       2022-11-20     2384     253716  0.009396
```

---

### 2. Using `.groupby()` + `.unstack()` (when additional rows of each type exist)

Just to be on the safer side, if you do have multiple rows for "clicked" or "delivered" respectively for a given date (for example, 2 clicked rows and 4 delivered rows for the same date), you can sum the quantities to get a single clicked and a single delivered row, using `groupby` and then do the same process as above.

1. Group by Day and Status columns and take sum of counts
2. Unstack the Status index to get 2 columns, `Clicked` and `Delivered`
3. Simply divide these 2 columns after that and reset index

```
g = df.groupby(['Day','Status'])['Count'].sum().unstack() #<-- Unstack status index
g['Ratio'] = g['Clicked']/g['Delivered']                  #<-- Divide clicked & delivered
g = g.reset_index()                                       #<-- Reset index
print(g)
```

```
Status         Day  Clicked  Delivered     Ratio
0       2022-11-08     1132     288322  0.003926
1       2022-11-13     4684     246203  0.019025
2       2022-11-19     1222     154872  0.007890
3       2022-11-20     2384     253716  0.009396
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solution solved all my problems.